# Repainting a frame on mouse click?

Tags: java, swing

I'm currently trying to make a game with a GUI that needs to paint new things on the screen on button clicks. For example:

```
public class GUI() extends JPanel {
    public void paintComponent() {
      /*
       *Basic initial set up here
       */

      // ***** Call method here on mouse click ***** 
    }
    public void setUpGUI() {
        JFrame mainFrame = new JFrame();
        GUI paintGUI = new GUI();
        clickDetector click = new clickDetector();

        mainFrame.addMouseListener(click);
        mainFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        mainFrame.setSize(500, 500);
        mainFrame.getContentPane().add(paintGUI);
        mainFrame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        GUI gui = new GUI();
        gui.setUpGUI();
    }
}
```

I need to implement a method in the `// ***** Call method here on mouse click *****` that will paint on the new additions to the frame (in my case these are circles that represent pieces on the board) but I'm unsure of how to do this on a button click. How can I repaint the frame each time the mouse is clicked so that I can modify my game board?

----EDIT----

Here is my paintComponent code, along with the listener being used to repaint.

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        System.out.println("Method called");
        g.setColor(Color.red);

        for(int y = 0; y < 6; y++) {
            for(int x = 0; x < 7; x++) {
                g.fillOval(x*70 + 10, y*70 + 10, 50, 50);
            }
        }

        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.fillRect(0, 430, 500, 50);
        g.setColor(Color.white);
        g.drawString("CONNECT FOUR", 250, 450);
        g.setColor(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
        click.paintPiece(g);

    }

public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        this.repaint();     

    }
```

Here is the method that paintComponent should be calling, but is not

```
public void paintPiece(Graphics g) {
        int x = getMouseX() + 10;
        int y = mover.getRow() + 10;
        g.fillOval(x, y, 50, 50);
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried calling `repaint()` when a mouse click is received?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just create a mouse listener:

```
MouseListener listen = new MouseListener()
{
    void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e){}
    void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e){}
    void mousePressed(MouseEvent e){paintGUI.repaint();}
    void mouseExited(MouseEvent e){}
    void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e){}
};
paintGUI.addMouseListener(listen);
```

Every time you click inside of the `JPanel`, you should now see it repaint. Likewise, if you want to update when a `JButton` is pressed, just use `ActionListener` instead:

```
ActionListener listen = new ActionListener()
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){paintGUI.repaint();}
}
button.addActionListener(listen);
```

This should be placed in your `setUpGUI()` method.

Comment: Thanks for this idea, I didn't think to use a mouse listener in my class where the painting happens. I believe this will work although I have run into one problem. My board is definitely repainting now, but the method to add the pieces is not being called. I've added the code to my answer to show what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

Add a Action Event listener to the button.

[Oracle Docs Action Event Listener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html)

In the actionPerformed method add whatever needs to be added then call

repaint();

Comment: The OP did mention clicking on a **button**.  The best listener for a button is an `ActionListener` since it will react to both mouse *and keyboard* input.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Yeah, I missed that, I thought he said just on button click.  Good catch, Ill edit.

Answer (score 0):

This changes will let you paint a rectangle each time you click on the frame

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class GUI extends JPanel implements MouseListener{
    private Rectangle rect;
    private int width = 100;
    private int height = 100;

    public GUI(int x, int y, int width, int height)
    {
        rect = new Rectangle(x, y, width, height);
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;
        g2d.draw(rect);
    }

    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        rect = new Rectangle(e.getX(), e.getY(), width, height);
        repaint();
    }


    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public void setUpGUI() {
        JFrame mainFrame = new JFrame();

        mainFrame.addMouseListener(this);
        mainFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        mainFrame.setSize(500, 500);
        mainFrame.getContentPane().add(this);
        mainFrame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        GUI gui = new GUI(0,0,100,100);
        gui.setUpGUI();
    }


}
```

Notice the `MouseListener` was implemented by the `GUI` class and when you are trying to initialize the `MouseListener` for the frame, you are just putting `this` as parameter, which will refer to the `GUI` class and therefore to your `JPanel`